# Grouping results from XPathSelectElements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml in the following structure

```
<root>     
    <Node>
        <value>a</value>
        <value>b</value>
        <value>c</value>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <value>d</value>
        <value>e</value>
        <value>f</value>

    </Node>
    <Node>
        <value>x</value>
        <value>y</value>
    </Node>  
</root>
```

I want to use the XPath **./root/Node/value** to select the **value**  nodes grouped by their section into lists. So the outcome is 3 list [a, b, c], [d, e, f], [x, y].

How can I achieve that using C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? There are literally hundreds of examples of reading XML in C# if you just search for it.

Comment: Show your current code so we can tell you where you're making a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq To Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

var lists = xDoc.Descendants("Node")
            .Select(n => n.Elements("value").Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

**OR**

```
var lists = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Node/value")
            .GroupBy(x => x.Parent)
            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ to XML` to easily achieve your goal. In most cases it is good to have your collection as `IEnumerable` instead of `List`.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = doc.Descendants("Node")
            .Select(n => n.Elements().Select(e => e.Value));
```